# Find modulo of multiplication of two number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, big-numbers

Given $m$, $a$ and $b$ are very big numbers, how do you calculate $ (a*b)\pmod m$ ?

As they are very big number I can not calculate $(a*b)$ directly. So I need another method.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are not already reduced mod $m$, reducing them first helps. Ultimately, though, I think you have to at least partially compute the product of the two numbers.

Comment: I'll do that for sure. But I want to know how to achieve it after computing $\pmod m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no general shortcuts besides reducing the terms of the product before multiplying. I will emphasize that by reduction, I mean picking the smallest representative mod $m$ ***in absolute value***. This may be a negative integer.

Having said that, there are tricks that can be used in special cases. The most basic integer arithmetic on a computer is not actually integer arithmetic, but rather, modulo $2^n$ for some $n$ (usually 32 or 64). Since the integers are represented in binary, bits do not need to be computed in the product after the $n+1$<sup>st</sup> bit has been computed, because those higher bits only contribute 0's. In general, if your integers are represented in base $e$, and $m$ divides $e^k$, then you don't have to compute the digits of the product above the $k+1$ term.

Another trick is to factor $m$ and use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to work with smaller numbers.

I'm sure there are many other tricks I've missed as well. If you're looking for a general algorithm, though, you won't find one that avoids arduous multiplication in all cases. Besides, multiplication is actually easy for a computer to do. Are you trying to do this by hand, or are the numbers really too big for a computer to handle?

Comment: Since you used the $a \mod m$ notation, it occurs to me that you might not already know about modular arithmetic, which is slightly different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.

Comment: The number is too big. It should overflow computers integer boundary by definition.

Comment: Do you mean that the product is larger than your computer's maxint? There are tools for multiplying numbers larger than the so-called maxint.

Comment: If that's the case, then this is a computer science question rather than a math question.

Answer (score 5):

If $a,b,m$ are integers then you can use following property :

$a \equiv a_1 \pmod m \land b \equiv b_1 \pmod m \Rightarrow a\cdot b \equiv a_1 \cdot b_1 \pmod m$

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the binary representation of these two numbers.
Suppose we have to multiply (a*b)%c where 0<=a,b,c<=10^18.
Then we can use this method:

```
ull mulmod(ull a,ull b,ull c){
    if(a<=1000000000ULL && b<=1000000000ULL){
        ull ret = ((a%c)*(b%c))%c;
        return ret;
    }
    ull ret = 0ULL, a=a%c;
    while(b > 0ULL){
        if(b&1ULL) {
            ret = (ret+a)%c;
        }
        a = (a<<1ULL)%c;
        b>>=1ULL;
    }
    return ret%c;
}
```

Hope this helps !